# Executing docker run command from config file

Tags: docker, config

I have several arguments in my docker run command like

```
docker run --rm -v /apps/hastebin/data:/app/data --name hastebin -d -p 7777:7777 -e STORAGE_TYPE=file rlister/hastebin
```

Can I put all the arguments of this in a default/config file so that I dont have to mention it explicitly in the run command?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

> With Compose, you use a Compose file to configure your application’s services. Then, using a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration

In your case `docker-compose.yml` file will looks like

```
version: '2'
services:
   hastebin:
     image: rlister/hastebin
     ports:
       - "7777:7777"
     volumes:
       - /apps/hastebin/data:/app/data
     environment:
       - STORAGE_TYPE=file
```

And you can run service by command `docker-compose up`

Comment: sorry i forgot add this to answer. command will be `docker-compose up`. Of course you need to install docker-compose but it is worthwhile.

Comment: Thats a nice approach but is there anything without installing extra dependencies?